# Is There Anyway To Retrieve The Label/Tag of a PR After Merged to Main?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-repos

I am looking to implement a automated SemVer process.

Lets say I have a PR open which has the label/tag of major, is there anyway to retrieve this tag AFTER it has been merged to main?

When the PR gets merged to main, I want to then trigger a pipeline which reads the label and then automatically bumps the tag version on the repo, is this possible in Azure DevOps? I know this can be done in GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

We can use the two REAT API [Pull Request Labels - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-request-labels/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.2) and [Annotated Tags - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/annotated-tags/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.2&tabs=HTTP) to complete the process.

The following is my test steps:

1. Create a [Personal Access Token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=Windows#create-a-pat) with Code permisson.
2. Create a pipeline with the following yaml in the main branch.
3. Create a secret Variable named `PAT` with the Personal Access Token in the pipeline.[image]

```
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: Windows-latest

jobs:
  - job: A
    condition: eq(contains(variables['Build.SourceVersionMessage'], 'Merged PR'), True)
    steps:
    - task: PowerShell@2
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          # Set your Azure DevOps organization, project, repository
          $organization = ""
          $project = ""
          $repositoryId = ""  #repo name or repo id

          $token="$(PAT)"
          $base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f "",$token)))

          $string = "$(Build.SourceVersionMessage)"
          $splitString = $string.Split(" ")
          $pullRequestId = $splitString[2].Replace(":", "")

          Write-Host "pullRequestId is $pullRequestId"
          
          # Invoke the REST API to get the label for the pull request
          $uri = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/git/repositories/$repositoryId/pullRequests/$pullRequestId/labels?api-version=7.1-preview.1"
          try {
              $labelResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
              $labelName = $labelResponse.value[0].name
              Write-Host "Label for Pull Request $pullRequestId : $labelName"
          } catch {
              Write-Host "Error retrieving label for Pull Request $pullRequestId : $_"
              exit 1
          }
          

          $tagName = $labelName 
          $tagMessage = "Release $tagName"  
          $commitId = "$(Build.SourceVersion)"  

          # Invoke the REST API to create the annotated tag
          $uri = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/git/repositories/$repositoryId/annotatedtags?api-version=7.1-preview.1"
          $tagBody = @{
              name = $tagName
              taggedObject = @{
                  objectId = $commitId
              }
              message = $tagMessage
          }
          try {
              $tagResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Post -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Body ($tagBody | ConvertTo-Json) -ContentType 'application/json'                   
              # Extract the tag URL
              $tagUrl = $tagResponse.url
              Write-Host "Annotated tag created: $tagUrl"
          } catch {
              Write-Host "Error creating annotated tag: $_"
              exit 1
          }
```

The pipeline has a condition in the job, so the job will only run when the `Build.SourceVersionMessage` contains the words "Merged PR". If not, the job will be skipped. [image]

Then we use the REST API in the PowerShell script to get the tag value from the PR and add tag to the branch.

Test Result:

1. Create a PR to main branch with tag 3.0.0
   [image]
2. The pipeline is triggered and running.
   [image]
3. The tag is added after the pipeline runs successfully.
   [image]
   [image]